# Vagrant and Chef... utterly astounding amount of version conflicts, now have mysql issue

Tags: mysql, ruby, vagrant, chef-solo

I'm trying my hardest to get Vagrant/Chef up and running. I used it a couple of years ago without much issue, but this is just... frustrating. I've tried all sorts of things to get it to work, and have probably ploughed 20+ hours into this in the past 4 days. This is the furthest I've gotten with it. I can't find anything about this particular error relating to mysql. Any advice from Chef experts?

```
==> default: [2014-06-16T22:07:08+02:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.4.2 ***
==> default: [2014-06-16T22:07:08+02:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["role[vagrant-test-box]"] from JSON
==> default: [2014-06-16T22:07:08+02:00] INFO: Run List is [role[vagrant-test-box]]
==> default: [2014-06-16T22:07:08+02:00] INFO: Run List expands to [apt, build-essential, openssl, apache2, apache2::mod_php5, mysql, mysql::server, php, php::module_mysql, apache2::vhosts, database::mysql, nodejs]
==> default: [2014-06-16T22:07:08+02:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for www.example.vm
==> default: [2014-06-16T22:07:08+02:00] INFO: Running start handlers
==> default: [2014-06-16T22:07:08+02:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
==> default: 
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default: Recipe Compile Error in /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-2/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/provider_mysql_service_suse.rb
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: NoMethodError
==> default: -------------
==> default: undefined method `require_relative' for main:Object
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: Cookbook Trace:
==> default: ---------------
==> default:   /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-2/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/provider_mysql_service_suse.rb:3
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: Relevant File Content:
==> default: ----------------------
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-2/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/provider_mysql_service_suse.rb:
==> default: 
==> default:   1:  require 'chef/provider/lwrp_base'
==> default:   2:  require 'shellwords'
==> default:   3>> require_relative 'helpers'
==> default:   4:  
==> default:   5:  extend Opscode::Mysql::Helpers
==> default:   6:  
==> default:   7:  class Chef
==> default:   8:    class Provider
==> default:   9:      class MysqlService
==> default:  10:        class Suse < Chef::Provider::MysqlService
==> default:  11:          use_inline_resources if defined?(use_inline_resources)
==> default:  12:  
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: [2014-06-16T22:07:08+02:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
==> default: [2014-06-16T22:07:08+02:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
==> default: [2014-06-16T22:07:08+02:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> default: [2014-06-16T22:07:08+02:00] FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `require_relative' for main:Object
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

Comment: You don't happen to be using Ruby version < 1.9.3 ? Because `require_relative` was introduced in that version.

Comment: Aha! Ok... Something else for me to look into. I just did a fresh install of the newest VirtualBox and Vagrant. Added the lastest lucid32 box, which I would assume is up-to-date. It appears that the mysql recipe I'm using (from the opscode community) requires chef 11, which requires ruby > 1.9. Argh! I remember when all this was easy! Now it's a complete mess of interdependencies!